# Stackelberg equilibrium with n+1 firms

Tags: microeconomics, game-theory, self-study

There are (n+1) firms (Firm 0, Firm 1, ..., Firm n) in a market for a good where $n \ge 2$. The price in the market is given by the inverse demand equation $P = 100 - \sum_{i=0}^n q_i$, where $\sum_{i=0}^n q_i$ is the total output in the market and $q_i$; is the quantity produced by Firm i. For simplicity assume that the cost is 0 for each firm. The firms choose their quantities as follows: (1) Firm 0 chooses its output level $q_0$ (2) After observing Firm 0's choice, the remaining n firms simultaneously choose their outputs. Each firm wants to maximize its profits. What is the Stackelberg Equilibrium for this market?

I found SPNE={$q_0^*=50$, $q_i=50/(n-1)$} for all $i\ge 1$

But I don’t know exactly how I can solve this question.

Please help me to solve this question

Comment: Are costs normalized to 0?

Comment: @MatteoBulgarelli yes, true!

Comment: It seems you did everything correctly!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit: I didn't see that it's a two-stage game. I considered an $n$-stage game in my previous answer. Here's the new modified answer:

The leader firm is denoted by $F_0$ and the next $n$ firms by $F_i$ where $i = 1,2, \cdots, n$.

Let's say $F_0$ chooses quantity $q_0$. The second stage is basically a Cournot competition between the firms $F_1, \cdots, F_n$. We will solve this first.

The profit of $F_i$ $(i > 0)$ is $\pi_i = (100 - Q)q_i$ which is maximized at $q_i = \frac{1}{2} \left( 100 - Q_{-i} \right)$ where $Q_{-i}$ denotes $Q - q_{i}$.

Clearly, the optimal $q_i = 100 - Q$ which means they are all equal (for $i > 0$). From this, it can be deduced that $q_i = 100 - q_0 - nq_i \implies q_i = \frac{100 - q_0}{n+1}$ $\forall \ i > 0$.

The first stage game can now be solved as $$q_0 = \text{argmax}[\pi_1(q_0)] = \text{argmax}[P(Q)q_0] = \text{argmax}\left[\left(\frac{100 - q_0}{n+1}\right)q_0\right] = 50$$

Consequently, the remaining firms produce $\displaystyle q_i = \frac{50}{n+1}$ $(i > 0)$.

Comment: I am confused at a point. You found $q_1^*=50$, which means firm 0’s output (the leader firm defined in the question). Or, This is two stage game. So, you calculated the output in the last stage (by backward induction) and you left the calculation of first stage for firm 0?

Comment: By the way, thank you for your great help:)

Comment: If you see, I mentioned that I will use notations $F_1, F_2, \cdots, F_n$. Instead of $n+1$ firms, I am considering $n$ firms (as it doesn't make a difference). The leader is $F_1$, then $F_2$ chooses and then $F_3$ and so on. The leader $(F_1)$ will produce $50$ units, followed by $25$ units by $F_2$, $12.5$ units by $F_3$ and so on.

Comment: I understand now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: That's wrong. Every firm has the same best response function, you sum up the FOCs  and back out  $q_i(q_1, ..., q_n)$. Then , and only then, you solve the first problem. You can't plug the BR of a player into the profits another player that plays simoultaneously and optimize...

Comment: Only one firm has a first mover advantage

Comment: @MatteoBulgarelli Thanks for the catch! I thought it's an $n$-stage game.

Comment: Thanks for updating! $\text{armgax}$ made my day lmao.

Comment: @MatteoBulgarelli Haha